# Insert into 2 tables from 1 form. Mysql Transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The user will create an article and submit an image with it.

+The article will go to the articles table.

+The image will go to images table (so that it can be used in other areas of the site).

**It has been suggested I use TRANSACTIONS but I am getting errors.**

```
    $sql ='BEGIN INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date)
            VALUES (?, ?, NOW())
            INSERT INTO images(article_id, image_caption)
            VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?);
            COMMIT';

 $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['article_name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['image_caption']);

        $OK = $stmt->execute();

        printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

        $stmt->free_result();

    } else{
        echo "Failure- article not uploaded";
    }
```

Comment: "I am getting errors". What errors do you get, then ?

Comment: You are just missing a semi-colon between 2 INSERT statements

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (?, ?, NO' at line 2

Comment: do you have any auto-increment column for table `articles`?

Comment: yes, I have article_id as an auto-increment.

Comment: OK. Ithink it is not a MySQL problem here. What `$conn->stmt_init()` return to you?

Comment: I updated my answer. Looks like you need to start transaction before your queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['article_name'], $_POST['description']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO images (article_id, image_caption) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['image_caption']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (?, ?, NO' at line 2

Comment: I think using single quotes is causing the interpreter to think NOW() is a string, but is not surrounded by quotes itself. You may try to surround it by double quotes, or use a variable with the DateTime expression

Comment: Royal - I removed the now/date parts and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using PDO (nice!). With PDO, you can get your transactions in an easy way with [beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) and [commit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

Your code would look like:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
// .. fire your 'normal' queries.
// .. and yet some more queries
$pdo->commit();
```

Then, I'd personally write separate `INSERT` queries in just two separate statements. More readable in my opinion.

Example:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$first = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (field, otherField) VALUES(?,?)');
$second = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (field, otherField) VALUES(?,?)');

$first->execute(array( .. your data (values) .. ));
$second->execute(array( .. your data (values) .. ));

$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: Before and after your queries.

Comment: $pdo->beginTransaction();
       
$sql ='INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date)
VALUES (?, ?, NOW())
INSERT INTO images(article_id, image_caption)';
     
$pdo->commit();

Comment: I got a fatal error with that. Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object

Comment: You are just creating a var called 'sql'. Further, my recommendation is to split it up over multiple queries. Next to that, in my example I called it $pdo and in your sample you called it $conn. Are you sure you know what you're doing?

Comment: sorry yes I switched it to $conn. I'm unclear how to use beginTransaction()

Comment: $conn->beginTransaction();

$sql = $conn->exec("INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");

$sql = $conn->exec("INSERT INTO images(article_id, image_caption)  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?)");

$conn->commit();

Comment: $conn->beginTransaction();

$first = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
$second = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO images(article_id, image_caption)  VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?)');

$first->execute(array( $article_name, $article_description));
$second->execute(array( $image_caption ));

$conn->commit();

Comment: Arthur's solution worked.Thanks so much I learned a lot from you. I think ultimately I would like to learn your way, it seems like it would be a good way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql ='START TRANSACTION;
       INSERT INTO articles (article_id,article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (NULL,?, ?, NOW());
       INSERT INTO images (article_id, image_caption) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?);
       COMMIT;';
```